# Prove that for $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean metric, any point in an open set $U \subset X$ is an accumulation point of $U$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This question seems to come up a lot of past papers and i cannot find a solution anywhere and I am completely confused so thought I would ask on here.

Prove that for $X=\mathbb{R}^n $ with the euclidean metric, any point in an open set $U \subset X$ is an accumulation point of $U$.

Any help much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be open, and what is an accumulation point. If you know the answers to these questions, the proof should be fairly direct.

Comment: I do but i dont know how to make a proof from these..

Comment: What you need is that an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains a __lot__ of points. Infinitely many. Every neighbourhood of $x\in U$ by definition contains an open ball around $x$. That ball contains a ball that is entirely in $U$. That ball contains infinitely many points of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is open and $x\in U$, then there exists an open ball $B_r(x)$, of radius $r$ and with $x$ its center, such that $B_r(x)\subset U$.

Observe then that
$$
x_j=x+r\frac{e_1}{j} \in B_r(x)\subset U, 
$$
for all $j>1$, where $e_1=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$. Thus apart from $x$, there is a whole sequence of distinct points arbitrarily close to $x$.

Thus $x$ is an accumulation point of $U$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Is this a full proof? Many thanks

Comment: Yes it is a full proof. See update.